# Is there an official website for scrum?

Tags: scrum

There are a number of websites out there that have different messages regarding scrum. For example, some websites state that items can be added to the sprint backlog AFTER the sprint has commenced, while others say that this is not allowed under any circumstances. I have found numerous other contradictions.

Is there an official website or resource for learning scrum?

Comment: More than blindly follow what sites are stating as correct, I understand what you want to find is _why_ they're advocating in favour or against adding items on-flight, since at the end of the day you must understand what better fits into _your_ reality.

Comment: Yes. A rationale is for action is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Although the scrum guide does say that if not taken in its entirety, the framework is not scrum. The official guide posted on ScrumGuides.org is what I'll follow, and if there are multiple ways of doing things, I'll try to find their rationales before employing them.

Comment: I believe that too often we try to adapt frameworks to our processes (because we think we're too unique or special or an exception to the rule) before putting in enough effort to adapt our processes to the framework, but still expect the benefits of that framework. If you want banana bread, follow the banana bread recipe. You can use more milk than the recipe calls for, and that's fine if you like it that way, but be aware that you might need to increase/reduce other ingredients to compensate and you might not get exactly the same cake that's on the picture.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[ScrumGuides.org](http://www.scrumguides.org/faq.html) is run and maintained by the co-creators of Scrum, Ken Schwaber and Jeff Sutherland. This site is the official Scrum site.

Of particular interest to you, is this quote.

> During the Sprint:
>
> - No changes are made that would endanger the Sprint Goal;
> - Quality goals do not decrease; and,
> - Scope may be clarified and re-negotiated between the Product Owner and Development Team as more is learned.

So, yes. Items theoretically may be added to the sprint, provided that it does not endanger the sprint goal.

Of course, in reality, adding new stories mid sprint is very likely to endanger the sprint goal. That is why you often see it "forbidden".

Answer (score 4):

Whether there is an official website for scrum and whether there is an official website for *learning* about scrum are two slightly different questions, even though the answer to both is no.

The three "most official" sites are the following:

- [ScrumGuides.org](http://scrumguides.org) - The official home of the Scrum Guide itself, which is the document that defines scrum. It's a good read; not just because it helps you understand the framework, but because you will see what vanilla scrum is. A lot of what people evangelize as part of scrum (e.g. story points, burndowns...) are useful but not really a part of scrum.
- [ScrumAlliance.org](https://www.scrumalliance.org) - Co-founded in 2002 by Ken Schwaber, one of the fathers of scrum. This organization issues the Certified Scrum Master (CSM) and Certified Product Owner (CSPO) certifications. The CSM is currently the best-known scrum certification.
- [Scrum.org](https://www.scrum.org) - Founded by Ken Schwaber in 2009 after leaving ScrumAlliance. This organization issues the Professional Scrum Master (PSM) and Professional Product Owner (PSPO) certifications. The PSM is gaining mind share.

[This page](http://www.scrumguides.org/history.html) helps summarize the differences between ScrumAlliance.org and Scrum.org.